# how to create a Json String in blackberry

Tags: json, blackberry

How i create an Json array like -

```
{"genres":[{"genre":[{"code":"CTY","name":"Country"}]},{"genre":[{"code":"HOP","name":"Hip Hop"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject jArrayFacebookFriendsData = new JSONObject();

JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();

try {
      jObjectData.put("friend_name",name_);
      jObjectData.put("friend_id", id_);
      jObjectData.put("friend_email", "null");
      jObjectData.put("friend_phone", "null");
      jArrayFacebookFriendsData.accumulate("friends",jObjectData);
    } 
   catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

Answer (score 4):

download json api from following link:

https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/

Create JSOn Object by using:

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();

obj.put("key", value);
```

here value may be any primitive type String, int, boolean, long...

Comment: how to add an array of values into json ?